# Behaviour of mailto links in fullscreen web app on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, mailto

When clicking on a mailto: link on a page in Mobile Safari on iOS 5 the following happens:

1. Mail.app appears in a vertical 'slide up' transition.
2. On clicking 'Send' or 'Cancel' Mail.app disappears in a vertical 'slide down' transition and the user is returned to the page in Mobile Safari.

However after selecting 'Add to Home Screen' and running the page in full screen mode the behaviour of the link changes:

1. Mail.app appears in a horizontal 'swap' transition.
2. On clicking 'Send' or 'Cancel' Mail.app does not disappear and the user has to switch back to the app manually.

Ideally I'd like the user to be automatically returned to the app when running in full screen mode.

I've tried the following:

- Running with and without `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`
- Using `window.location.replace` or `window.location.assign()` with `event.preventDefault() / return false` as suggested in [Error when using mailto: link in Mobile Safari in app-capable mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943698/error-when-using-mailto-link-in-mobile-safari-in-app-capable-mode)

Is there any way to achieve this? I suspect not but it would be nice to get a definitive answer!

EDIT: This question is based on an HTML web page loaded into the standard iOS browser via http, not a native iOS app embedding Mobile Safari.

Comment: I have an issue like this.  After sending or cancelling e-mail there is no way to automatically get back to the web application. Surely someone at Apple thought about this. Unless a solution is found for this it seems like the death knell of using client e-mail in mobile web applications.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method, check the url scheme for 'mailto', then perform your own action instead of the default action.

Then send email and it will remain in your app.

Comment: Thanks, however this is an HTML web page loaded into the standard iOS browser, not a native iOS app embedding Mobile Safari. I've edited the question to make this clearer.