# Using mailto on the html, how can I open the email app from Safari in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, safari, mailto

I have a simple form with a button to open an email window.
On my laptop, using Chrome, everything works fine. But on my iPhone, it doesn't open the email app.

This is the HTML

```
<form action="mailto:myemail@hotmail.com" method="post">
    <Button type="submit" class="button">Contact Me Now</Button>
</form>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672339/2431281)? You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2471032/2431281) too.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with this code:
<div class="button">
        <a href="mailto:voets_thomas@hotmail.com">Contact Me Now</a>
      </div>

Comment: Oh, now that you mention it, most of the answers I shared has their html elements as *anchors* instead of *buttons*. You can post that as an answer to your own question, then accept it yourself so that we can be able to close this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I removed the form and used an anchor tag instead.

```
<div class="button">
   <a href="mailto:email@hotmail.com">Contact Me Now</a>
</div>
```